# Windows 10 client GPO to favor DHCP server over another one

Tags: cisco, windows-server-2012-r2, dhcp, windows-10

We have a cisco RV180W and a Windows server 2012R2, both acting as DHCP servers, the cisco is here to serve IP's if our server is down, but it's been a week since it has taken the lead into DHCP response time and is being taken as DHCP server by the clients, causing connectivity issues.

Because there is no way of setting a delay into the interface of our cisco router, I wanted to know if a GPO could be deployed to our client asking them to wait for our Windows server DHCP to give them an IP...

Thanks you for reading.

Comment: You do not have an issue with GPO as much as someone was simlpy making serious beginner mistakes setting up both DHCP. A proper configuration would not have any connectivity issues if the Cisco takes the lead. In fact, if it is a backup and causes connectivity issues - it is not much of a backup to start with. Fix that.

Comment: hello @TomTom, I have not the possibility to act on this part of the network, only on the system part, I wish I could but for historic reasons (what I've been told) I can't act on that thing. I wanted to ask more qualified people than me on windows GPO's because i'm from the debian sphere of doing things. Also downvoting while not giving me the option to explain the context is sad.

Comment: Well, bad news: software generally is not designed with ridiculous company decisions in mind. There is no GPO because it makes no sense. Fix your network. Reconfigure the broken DHCP. Fixed.

Comment: Than how about giving me lead on how to fix it so I can advise network side people on how is it solvable? As I see things, there are 2 separate dhcp ranges, each served by either the cisco router or WinSer2012, but the clients only recognise the domain on the range served by the windows 2012 server. How should we do it properly?

Comment: The IP range is only one part of what DHCP serves. I would say the DHCP parameters are not correct. It is for example likely that neither default route or domain name are sent. Of the DNS servers are bad. In which case the clients will not find the domain. A step by step comparison of the DHCP configuration is needed. Technically - there is no need for DHCP on Cisco, btw . -Server 2012 if you hhave multipe can do replication between servers.

Comment: Well, there is for now only one server hosting a few virtual machines that are windows, so the idea here was certainly to still have ip connectivity if we lose the physical server. We do not yet have another VMhost to place dhcp replication on it. DNS servers are sent correctly, but I can't specify domain name and route into our cisco's dhcp configuration, there are no fileds for that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35488/discussion-between-kuzko-and-tomtom).

Comment: No such GPO exists. As TomTom has....eloquently....put it, you have an architectural issue, not a client configuration issue.

Comment: thank you it's noted, I have what I need, I'm going to go through our IT architecture and rework it, because it seems that it needs to be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the DHCP clients are members of an Active Directory domain then you don't need to configure a DNS suffix or domain name for them in DHCP as they already have that by virtue of their AD domain membership. You need to make sure that the DHCP server on the router is assigning the DHCP clients a valid and correct ip address, subnet mask, DNS server(s) and default gateway.

That being said, the DHCP server needs to assign the AD DNS server to the DHCP clients, and if that server is down then you'll be in a bit of a catch 22.

Additionally, a running Windows DHCP client won't lose it's DHCP ip configuration when the DHCP server goes down. It will lose it's DHCP ip configuration if it reaches the Rebinding phase (T2) of the DHCP lease renewal/rebinding process if the DHCP server is down.

Having a single Domain Controller (that is also your AD DNS server and DHCP server) is a recipe for disaster. You're better served by setting up an additional DC/DNS/DHCP server then you are trying to make the router perform the DHCP server role.

Comment: It's noted, thank you for your clear explanations !

Comment: Glad to help...